# I am using a bluetooth left-handed mouse in 12.04 LTS 64bit. How to make it permanently left-handed?

Tags: 64-bit, mouse, bluetooth

I need to set buttons manually with xinput set-button-map id 3 2 1 ... The mouse is Eclipse Touch Mouse. Connection was established using standard Ubuntu bluetooth feature without passcode. The left-handed setting resets after short inactivity time (probably mouse gets into sleep mode or something like this) and mouse gets back to right-hand mode. How can I make the setting for left-hand use permanent, so that I can use my mouse left-handed all the time without the need to set button map manually? I am a total beginner in Ubuntu world. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to set it from System settings? Go to *System Settings > Mouse (and Touchpad)* and check *Left-handed*.

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest solution but I forgot to add that other people like my wife for example uses mouse device (different mouse) right-handed. I guess it would need switching between different settings depending on which person uses Ubuntu which is not the most convenient solution.

Comment: Do you all use the same accout? Setting of an account doesn't affect others'.

Comment: Yes, we use the same account. It is easier when juest one of us wants to check an e-mail or drop a word to a friend - no point to have two machines powered-on all the time.

Comment: Then I'll suggest a shortcut: Go to *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts* and bind a shortcut to `xinput set-button-map id 3 2 1`. This won't solve the problem but it is faster than opening the terminal and writing down the command every time.

Comment: Thank you for trying to find a solution. You put it very accurately - doesn't solve the problem but helps to deal with it better.